# Add Object to Array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, types, addition

I'm new to matlab and I can't add an object to an array:

```
%g is a transfer function
h = bodeplot(g);
% class('h') prints 'resppack.bodeplot'
a = zeros(2,1);
a(1,1) = h;
% I get the error: Conversion to double from resppack.bodeplot is not possible.
```

This happens because my matrix 'a' is of type double while 'h' isn't.
How can I define an array of type 'resppack.bodeplot'?
resppack.bodeplot doesn't have an 'empty' method...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Btw you can use a cell array for that

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, i s that you create an array of doubles, and you want to store other things.

You can not initialize the array and start adding objects like this:

```
my-array(1) = something
my-array(2) = something-2
...
```

> > new-array(1) = h

new-array =

```
resppack.bodeplot
```

> > new-array(2) = h

new-array =

```
resppack.bodeplot: 1-by-2
```

> > new-array

new-array =

```
resppack.bodeplot: 1-by-2
```

Comment: This answer could really use some editing for clarity, it's not at all clear.